# What are the differences between compiling assembly using gcc and as

Tags: gcc, assembly, raspberry-pi, gnu-assembler

I am learning how to use assembly language (on Raspberry Pi incidentally) and I am wondering what the difference is between using `gcc` and `as` to do the compiling.

So far, the differences I have noticed are:

- I should do the extra linking step with `as`.
- On the Raspberry Pi, `as` seems to recognize the architecture better than `gcc` by itself. I have to tell `gcc` the architecture before I can use instructions like integer division.
- With `gcc` I have easy access to the C standard library functions. I assume this is possible using `as` but I haven't figured it out yet.

I would like to stick to a particular compiler. What other differences should I be aware of. Is there an advantage / disadvantage to using either?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gcc` is just a front-end that runs `as` (and `ld` unless you use `-c` to stop at object files without linking).  Use `gcc -v` to see what it runs and what command line options it passes.

If you want to link with libraries, generally use `gcc`.  It knows the right command-line options to pass to `ld` to set library paths, and which order to put things in on the `ld` command line.

You might find `gcc -nostdlib` or `-nostartfiles` useful, e.g. if you want to write your own `_start` but still link libraries.  Also `-no-pie` and/or `-static` depending on how you want to link.

---

If you're curious to learn more about the toolchain and linking, then sure play around with `ld` options and see what breaks when you change the options.  And/or use `readelf -a` to examine the resulting executable.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372118/whats-the-relationship-between-gcc-linking-and-ld-linking) are some more detailed informations about the difference ìn linking between `gcc` and `ld`. Maybe it is helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the C standard library functios in assembly too. Just follow the [GCC calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/what-registers-to-save-in-the-arm-c-calling-convention) and use the standard `printf` [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442133/how-to-use-printf-in-raspberry-pi-assembly-language).
You have to compile your assembly program with `as` first to create an object file. After that you can use the linker to link all neccessarry libraries (`stdio` for example).

Comment: stdio functions are part of the standard C library.  On GNU/Linux systems like RPi, the library is `libc.so`.  The link option for `ld` is `-lc`